# xamarin no hardware acceleration when deployin to device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hardware-acceleration

I am developing a xamarin forms application right now and I have some problems with hardware acceleration.

Specifically, in the android emulator, hardware acceleration works, ie

```
System.Numerics.Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated
```

returns true.

On the device however, it returns false, and thus libraries like ImageSharp are super slow.

I already checked the build settings and "Optimize code" is checked everywhere. Also I added `HardwareAccelerated = true` to the MainActivity.cs in the android project, but that doesn't change anything.

Anybody can help?

EDIT:

The emulator is running on api level 25 (android 7.1), in the emulator it is working with debug configuration.

The device is running android 8.1, api level 27, and only release build work there at all.

EDIT:

According to @SushiHangover there is no Hardware acceleration support for System.Numerics.Vector for arm platforms implemented in Mono.
Also, see here: https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/94

Cheers, Johannes

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick scan of Mono's `mini-XXX.c` files and `mini-arm.c` and `mini-arm64.c` do not implement any SIMD versions.

Since there are no intrinsic support, the Mono JIT'er will not map SIMD (NEON) functions on supported ARM devices.

Note: Only `mini-amd64.c` & `mini-x86.c` have JIT intrinsic support for SIMD (SSE) within the Mono Runtime/JIT.

**Note:** According to one of the old Mono release notes, AOT'ing via LLVM should give you SIMD support on any supported platform... (I have not tested that)

**Update**: I tested `llvm` and the generated `libaot-System.Numerics.Vectors.dll.so` on ARM platforms is not hardware accelerated

Comment: That means I cannot get any hardware acceleration for System.Numerics.Vector on arm64? 
Then, do you know of any image library that is fast enough without hardware acceleration? Resizing an image without acceleration takes about 10 seconds in ImageSharp

Comment: @jaidmin I did not check if the AOT/LLVM code does anything special for SIMD/NEON, but you can give it a try (your APK will be huge, but you'll have fast code :-/ ) According to one of the old release notes, AOT'ing via LLVM should give you SIMD support on any supported platform... (I have not tested that)

Comment: @jaidmin On a couple of Android projects (Java and Xamarin/C#) that involved heavy image editing with near-realtime/interactive response, we used native C/C++ NDK code (as do most of the mainstream Android apps)