# ImageSharp extremely slow on Android devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-core, .net-standard, imagesharp

I'm building a Xamarin app, using **ImageSharp** for image manipulation.

I've noticed that the ImageSharp operations are very slow in the emulator and *ridiculously* slow when deployed to a physical device (Galaxy Note 8).

Things that are *way* slow:

```
// Load image (very slow)
var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(stream);   

// Manipulate image (equally slow)
image.Mutate(i => i.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                    {
                        Mode = ResizeMode.Pad,
                        Position = AnchorPositionMode.Top,
                        Size = new SixLabors.Primitives.Size(600,400))
                    }));
```

Note that the image loads fine (albeit slowly) and the resizing *works*, but it's very slow (30-60 seconds).

Executing the same code from a .NET Core console program reduces the load and manipulation times to about 1-2 seconds.

With the debugger attached, I see a flood of these when ImageSharp operations are running:

> GC_MINOR: (Nursery full)

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this, is my only option to clone the ImageSharp repo and debug using a custom build?

**Edit:** Not sure if this may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/451)?

**Edit #2:** I gave up on ImageSharp and also tested OpenCV to no particular avail and then settled on **SkiaSharp** which works great right out of the box.

Comment: There currently is no SIMD support via Xamarin, you would need a native C/C++/Java implementation  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433924/xamarin-no-hardware-acceleration-when-deployin-to-device/50434306?s=1|40.4283#50434306

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. :/ Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on SkiaSharp. I'm also using Imagesharp in a Blazor-app and it's unusably slow.

Comment: Just found out that SkiaSharp only works in Blazor serverside and not client-side